# Custom ListView Adapter Android

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

May i know why does my custom listview adapter look like this?

Image:

[image]

Codes:

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

CurrencyRatesDetails crd = new CurrencyRatesDetails();

TextView inputCurrTV, convertedAmtTV;
ListView currencyLV;
EditText inputAmtET;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
String[] currNameArr = crd.getNames();
String[] currCodeArr = crd.getCodes();
String[] currRateArr = crd.getRates();

Context context;

int index = 0;

//String[] rateCurrArr = {"AUD", "BGN", "BRL", "CAD", "CHF", "CNY"};
//double[] rateArr = {0.944, 1.2824, 2.2842, 0.96158, 0.70946, 4.8624}
Menu myMenu = null;

double rate, amtInput, finalConversion;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    context = this;

    inputAmtET = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputAmtET);
    convertedAmtTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.convertedAmtTV);
    inputCurrTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.inputCurrTV);
    currencyLV = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.currencyLV);

    //Resources myRes = this.getResources();
    //currArr =  myRes.getStringArray(R.array.currencyList);
    //adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.currencyList, android.R.layout.simple_selectable_list_item);
    //adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_selectable_list_item, currNameArr);
    //currencyLV.setAdapter(adapter);

    currencyLV.setAdapter(new CustomAdapterLV(this, currNameArr, currCodeArr, currRateArr));

    currencyLV.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

            inputCurrTV.setText(currCodeArr[i]);

            index = i;

            //Getting rate based on selected currency code
            //rate = rateArr[i];

        }
    });
}

public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    this.myMenu = menu;
    addMenuItems(menu);

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.mainmenu, menu);
    return true;
}

private void addMenuItems(Menu menu) {
    int index = 200;
    menu.add(index, index, index, "Settings");
    menu.add(index, index + 1, index + 1, "Add Custom Rate");
    menu.add(index, index + 2, index + 2, "Load Default Rates");
}

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    //getOrder() to get Menu Item at this specific orderId
    if (item.getOrder() == 123) {

        amtInput = Double.parseDouble(inputAmtET.getText().toString());

        //finalConversion = amtInput / rate;

        finalConversion = crd.conversion(amtInput, index);

        //Formatting converted value to 2d.p
        String finalValue = String.format("%.2f", finalConversion);

        convertedAmtTV.setText(finalValue);

    } else if (item.getItemId() == 201) {

        Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, CustomXchangeRate.class);
        startActivity(myIntent);

    }

    return true;
}
```

**Custom LV Adapter Layout.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_custom_lvadapter"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:weightSum="1"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0.0dp"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:layout_weight="0.13"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.7"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/currencyNameTV"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:text="text"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/currencyCodeTV"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="15px"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:text="text"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0.0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.3"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/currencyRateTV"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="text"
            android:textSize="30dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15px"
            android:layout_marginTop="15px"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Custom LV Adapter Class.java**

```
public class CustomAdapterLV extends BaseAdapter{

String[] resultNames;
String[] resultCodes;
String[] resultRates;

Context context;

private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;

public CustomAdapterLV(MainActivity mainActivity, String[] names,          String[]codes, String[] rates) {
    resultNames = names;
    resultCodes = codes;
    resultRates = rates;

    context = mainActivity;

    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return resultNames.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public class ViewHolder{
    TextView tvName;
    TextView tvCode;
    TextView tvRate;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder();
    View rowView;

    rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_custom_lvadapter, null);

    vh.tvName = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.currencyNameTV);
    vh.tvCode = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.currencyCodeTV);
    vh.tvRate = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.currencyRateTV);

    vh.tvName.setText(resultNames[position]);
    vh.tvCode.setText(resultCodes[position]);
    vh.tvRate.setText(resultRates[position]);

    return rowView;

}
```

currNameArr, currCodeArr, currRateArr are hardcoded in another class, cant seem to add it in.

Thanks guys..

Comment: It looks like a design problem, Does it look the same in the preview window?

Comment: yes that is what i got when i run my activity_main.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do a try, and I'm without editor so please give me a feedback.

Try using this layout: your textview is smaller than the height of the text probably

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_custom_lvadapter"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"

android:orientation="vertical">
<!-- I removed the weightsum because this linearlayout is containing only a single item. If you have more items tell me and I will edit it -->

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.7"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
      <!-- replaced width with 0dp also here -->

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/currencyNameTV"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:text="text"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/currencyCodeTV"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="15px"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:text="text"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.3"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/currencyRateTV"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="text"
            android:textSize="30dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15px"
            android:layout_marginTop="15px"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: @domster ahahah welcome, I added the explainations inside the layout as comments so check them for a more complete answer :)

Comment: @domster consider also flagging this as the answer so other users with same problem can easily find a solution

Comment: yup already did flag, thank you so much man! on the way to completing my assignment..

Answer (score 1):

This is the issue because of weigh given to text views in layout.
Here text views are cropping because of weight...no need to add weight..just remove it and give height as "wrap-content".

Answer (score -1):

focus **layout_weight** in your layout